# How do Interface methods perform functions in Java without body definition in it?

Tags: java, object, collections, interface, iterator

For example, `hasNext()` and `next()` methods in the Iterator interface perform their functions by checking whether there is a next line/object in a collection and returning the next object respectively, without overriding the methods.

Please help me understand.

The example code snippet below:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        list.add("A"); 
        list.add("B"); 
        list.add("C"); 
        list.add("D"); 
        list.add("E"); 

        // Iterator to traverse the list 
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); 

        System.out.println("List elements : "); 

        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " "); 

        System.out.println(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface methods *don't* perform functions, that's the whole point of an interface. They specify a *contract* that must be met by classes which implement them.

Read the documentation for `Iterator#hasNext`:

```
 * Returns {@code true} if the iteration has more elements.
 * (In other words, returns {@code true} if {@link #next} would
 * return an element rather than throwing an exception.)
 *
 * @return {@code true} if the iteration has more elements
```

All an interface says is *what any class implementing it must do*. The *how* is left up to the class implementing it, so the mechanism by which the check is done is left up to any class which implements Iterator.

In your example, the iterator is implemented in

`java.util.ArrayList.Itr`

Comment: Yes i agreed. But trying to understand little bit more, i could see the above methods are returning values without 'return' statement written inside them.

Comment: @AsikRahman.M I don't understand. Which methods are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, i understood now, so as you mentioned, `java.util.ArrayList.Itr` class has the implementation of `hasNext()` and `next()` methods right?

Comment: Yes. `Iterator` itself just defines the method signature (the types of the input parameters and the output type).

Comment: Okay Thanks @Ben R